# HDFS encryption: User:hdfs not allowed to do 'DECRYPT_EEK' on 'hdfskey'

Tags: hadoop, encryption, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-ranger

I'm trying to setup HDFS encryption with Ranger KMS on HDP 2.4.

I was able to deploy and configure the KMS service. I've created a key and an access policy to grant all permissions to hdfs user for operating with this key.

I'm able to create an encrypted zone with

```
sudo -uhdfs hdfs mkdir /data_enc
sudo -uhdfs hdfs crypto -createZone -keyName hdfskey  -path /data_enc
```

However when I try to put a file into the directory, I get this error:

```
    sudo -uhdfs hdfs dfs -put /tmp/file.txt /data_enc/
...
    User:hdfs not allowed to do 'DECRYPT_EEK' on 'hdfskey'
```

hdfs user has all permissions for this key, including DECRYPT_EEK. Does anyone knows what could go wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hdfs` user is blacklisted by default for decrypt operations in Ranger.
It is possible that this blacklisting is overriding the `DECRYPT_EEK` permission given to the key.

Edit the property `hadoop.kms.blacklist.DECRYPT_EEK` in either `Advanced dbks-site Menu` in Ranger or in `dbks-site.xml`.